# Javascript parser for logical expressions

Tags: javascript

I have expression like `5+10 > 4+1 or (3+10 < 5+1)`
i need to evaluate this expression to return true or false 
is there any JavaScript libraries that can help me in that

Comment: `eval`, `Function()` and `window.eval`. Pick one.

Comment: Do you simply mean converting the plain-English "`or`" into a proper logical "`||`" operator?  Seems unnecessary to include a library for that, although I agree with @IsmaelMiguel that you may be forced to use `eval`.

Comment: @Ismael It wouldnt be hard to parse it yourself, I am sure there are libraries that do that already, too and that is much safer than eval.

Comment: I tried eval but it doesn't work as it throws exceptions

Comment: If you want to use `eval()` you first have to replace `or` with `||`, `and` with `&&`, `not` with `!`

Comment: This is an interesting question but to properly answer it I think more context is required-- is this a string you are getting passed?  Or do you just need to evaluate some logic with an `or`/`||`?

Comment: https://npm.runkit.com/cross-safe-eval

Comment: @MoustafaTaha Then give us an expected input and the required output. Otherwise, it's just guessing.

Comment: @Marie I agree that they are safer and all, but the bloat is incredibly higher.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I need to evaluate expression like that 
'a and (b and c) and d or e and (f or g)'
where a/b is expression

Comment: @MoustafaTaha Add a **real** input and a **expected** output **to the question**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need library. Just:

```
var s = (5+10 > 4+1) || (3+10 < 5+1); //s is true
```